# How to set the settings of a command prompt using the batch file?

Tags: batch-file

```
       prompt $
       cls
       cmd 
       color 87
```

This is my batch file. It opens the command prompt but with its default settings.How can i change the color and prompt of a command prompt before i open it in a batch file? How do i make it? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmd /?` provides you with some useful information.

This should do what you want:

```
cmd /K "color 87"
```

Comment: thank you mod chip its working Do u have any tutorial regarding these?I mean how to set prompt and also how to exit a command line from the batch file Do u have any reference ?

Comment: Sadly, once you've opened a separate cmd process, the parent can't close the child, nor vice versa.

Fool around with `cmd /?` and `start /?` to learn more.